# How to change settings so I can upload images in Wordpress posts?

Tags: server

When I try to upload an image in a post on this WordPress site: http://richardclunan.com/

...I get the message "Unable to create directory **__**. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

How do I change settings so I can upload images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the admin panel and navigate to Settings>Media and see what it says in the Store uploads in this folder dialog box. You can try deleting whatever is in it and click save. WordPress will then try to use the default wp-content/uploads/images/2012... folders. If that doesn't work I'd FTP to my server and check the file permissions.